# Saving as order when paypal transaction cancelled by user

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-standard

How to save the order to order table under any state when the payment is cancelled via paypal standard.

Comment: Have you tried to change status from Configuration-->Order Status in magento admin panel.?

Comment: Nope, I am asking when cancel from paypal page. It return back to the shopping cart page. but I need the item to be saved as order under processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending few hours on this I first came to know that the magento 1.9 includes paypal Express along with paypal standard. so making this clear I just deactivated the express via sql changes and block rewrites (referring [some](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2015/06/magento-1-9-enable-both-paypal-standard-and-paypal-express-checkout/) external sources). coming back to the point we need an override for the paypal cancellation action. This can be obtained by an observer `sales_order_payment_cancel`, rest of the below codes explain other process as well. Hope this should help someone.

> ***local/Stackoverflow/Paypalstandard/etc/config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custom_paypalstandard>
                <class>Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard_Model</class>
            </custom_paypalstandard>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <custom_paypalstandard>
                <class>Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard_Block</class>
            </custom_paypalstandard>
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <standard_redirect>Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard_Block_Standard_Redirect</standard_redirect>
                    <adminhtml_system_config_fieldset_location>Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Fieldset_Location</adminhtml_system_config_fieldset_location>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
        </blocks>
        <events>
            <sales_order_payment_cancel>
                <observers>
                    <after_placing_order>
                        <class>custom_paypalstandard/observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </after_placing_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_cancel>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> ***local/Stackoverflow/Paypalstandard/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Fieldset/Location.php***

This is a part of override to deactivate the paypal express - for this please refer *[Some](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2015/06/magento-1-9-enable-both-paypal-standard-and-paypal-express-checkout/)* link.

> ***local/Stackoverflow/Paypalstandard/Block/Standard/Redirect.php***

```
class Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard_Block_Standard_Redirect extends Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect
{
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $standard = Mage::getModel('paypal/standard');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setAction($standard->getConfig()->getPaypalUrl())
            ->setId('paypal_standard_checkout')
            ->setName('paypal_standard_checkout')
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setUseContainer(true);
        foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
            $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));
        }
        $idSuffix = Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash();
        $submitButton = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Submit(array(
            'value'    => $this->__('Click here if you are not redirected within 10 seconds...'),
        ));
        $id = "submit_to_paypal_button_{$idSuffix}";
        $submitButton->setId($id);
        $form->addElement($submitButton);
        $html = '<html><body>';
        $html.= $this->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website in a few seconds.');
        $html.= $form->toHtml();
        $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("paypal_standard_checkout").submit();</script>';
        $html.= '</body></html>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

---

> **local/Stackoverflow/Paypalstandard/Model/Observer.php**

---

```
class Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard_Model_Observer
{

 public function implementOrderStatus($observer)
    {
        $payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL, false);
        $orderIds = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getNonCancelledOrders();
        if (!$orderIds) {
            $orderIds = array($order->getId());
        } else {
            $orderIds[] = $order->getId();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setNonCancelledOrders($orderIds);
    }
}
```

---

> **etc/modules/Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard.xml**

---

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Stackoverflow_Paypalstandard>
    </modules>
</config>
```